# Using dlib with darknet to detect object with keypoints

Tags: deep-learning, dlib, yolo, darknet

I'm trying to detect object with yolo after training the system to custom datasets using darknet of AlexeyAB,
Using dlib to detect object with keypoints like face is a good choice to optimize the precision of the object detection and i want to know if is there a way to use dlib with the darknet learning dataset output?
Thanks

Comment: https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet/issues/1030

Comment: this is not the same issue that i have , he use face recognition